# Can I structure document collection of users that sign in using google auth provider?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, react-redux-firebase

So I am trying to do an app using React and Firebase and by now everything was fine. 
In my app there are a few options to auth a user. Google, Email and Password and also Twitter. 
 
When a user is creating an account using his email I can easily structure how the data will look like in my firestore for that user and I do it that way:

```
firebase.createUser(
        { email, password },
        { 
            firstName, 
            lastName,
            emailAddress: email,
            birthDate: null,
            activeStatus: false,
            dateJoined: new Date(),
            avatarUrl: null,
            friends: [],
            posts: [
                {
                    content: "I have just joined!",
                    date: new Date(),
                    likes: [],
                    comments: [],
                    shares: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ).then(() => {
        history.push("/login")
    })
```

And the output in my firestore is something like that:
[Firestore screen - email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxIiu.png)

Now I want to structure my data of users that Signed In using Google auth the same way. 
This is how my Sign In using Google looks like:

```
const loginWithGoogle = () => {
    firebase.login({ provider: 'google', type: 'popup' })
    .then(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('authUser', auth)
        history.push("/home")
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message)
    })
}
```

And the output in the firestore by the default looks that way: [Firestore screen - google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgrG5.png)

So my question is: 

How do I even try to make both auth types collections look the same way? 
 Should I somehow find out that the user is signing in for the first time using google provider and then try to structure that collection or is there a better approach to do that? 


Thanks for all responses.


******************************* 
**For people who are struggling with that:

I did it thanks to @Ajordat response and this is how it looks and works perfectly fine for me:**

```
const loginWithGoogle = () => {
    firebase.login({ provider: 'google', type: 'popup' })
    .then((user) => {
        const fullName = user.profile.displayName.split(" ")
        
        const firstName = fullName[0]
        const lastName = fullName[1]

        if (user.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
            firestore.collection("users").doc(user.user.uid).set({
                ...user.profile,
                firstName,
                lastName,
                birthDate: null,
                activeStatus: false,
                dateJoined: new Date(),
                friends: [],
                posts: [
                    {
                        author: firstName + " " + lastName,
                        content: "I have just joined!",
                        date: new Date(),
                        likes: [],
                        comments: [],
                        shares: []
                    }
                ]
            })
        } else {
            console.log("user exists")
        }

        localStorage.setItem('authUser', auth)
        history.push("/home")
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message)
    })
}
```

Comment: You should check on [`AdditionalUserInfo.isNewUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo#isNewUser()) in order to know if it's the first time a user is logging in.

Comment: @Ajordat love you man I think it will work perfectly.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer. If you feel like it's correct do not hesitate to accept it. If you think it can be improved you can help by expanding it and later accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the method [`AdditionalUserInfo.isNewUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo#isNewUser()) in order to check if it's the first time a user is logging in. It will always be `false` except that one time, which you need to use to create the user on Firestore as you want it to be.